# Examine html code before displaying on UIWebView using ios swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to get a code that is sent to me in the title element of a web view. I need to send an initial request and display that view so that the user can input a password, then the response to that will be the view that I want with the code in the title element. Is there a way to get and examine the html code's title element before it gets displayed like some sort of function call from the UIWebView? I'm using this to send the initial request and to print the view with the code after I see it, but I don't really ever want to see it, I just want to examine the html and pull out the code in the title element.

```
 let url2 = NSURL(string: "myURLString") //real string is hidden

 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url2!) {(data, response, error) in
        print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

    task.resume()
   // later I push a button and print the current page when I see my code
   // on the web view with this
   webView.reloadInputViews()
    let html = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.all[0].outerHTML")
    // print(html)
    if let page = html{
        print(html)
    }
```

So is there a way to know that my webview has loaded a new page, or do i just have to continuously examine it and see if it has changed?